# Can I use Heroku to Scrape Data to later Download?

Tags: python, csv, heroku, web-scraping, download

I have a python script that **scrapes** data from different websites then writes some data into CSV files.

I run this every day from my local computer but I would like to make this automatically running on a server and possibly for free.

I tried PythonAnywhere but it looks that their whitelist stops me from scraping bloomberg.com.

I then passed to Heroku, I deployed my worker (the python script). Everything seems to work but looking with Heroku bash to the directory where the python script is supposed to write the CSV files nothing appears.

I also realised that I have no idea of how I would download those CSV files in case those were written.

I am wondering if I can actually achieve what I am trying to achieve with Heroku or if the only way to get a python script to work on a server is by paying for PythonAnywhere and avoid scraping restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku's filesystem is per-dyno and ephemeral. You must not save things to it for later use.

One alternative is to write it to somewhere permanent, such as Amazon S3. You can use the `boto` library for this. Although you do have to pay for S3 storage and data, it's very inexpensive.

Comment: could I not then do the same with any web sapce provider? or for some reason only Amazon S3 would work with Heroku?

Comment: What other ones are you thinking of? S3 is the usual solution for this kind of thing, but I guess Google and Microsoft have similar offerings. The point is you want something that will only charge for the data you store.

Comment: Yes Amazon is a pretty good solution but was thinking if a free web space as 000Webhost could be appropriate too.. keep in mind I am a newbie so probably a stupid question

Comment: But S3 or equivalent have APIs and libraries specially for uploading and retrieving individual files. A general web hosting service wouldn't have that.

Comment: can S3 run python too? at this point I do not need Heroku anymore.. right?